# CKEditor Upgrade from 4.1 to 4.4.7

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, upgrade

I'm having a couple of issues with my upgrade from 4.1 to 4.4.7:

1. Existing custom addons no longer work. I'm getting a JavaScript error
   on the following call in my init function, for example:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'pdf',
    {
    lang: 'de,en,es,fr,fr-ca',
    init : function( editor )
    {
       editor.addCommand( 'pdf', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand( 'pdf' ) );
    .
    .
    .
   ```

It no longer appears to recognize addCommand as a valid method.

2. After removing all plugins, I am able to get the editor to appear, however, my menus have disappeared.

Is there a clear upgrade path from 4.1 to the current version, or at least a list of deprecated methods?  I haven't been able to locate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably at least scan the [changelog](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/CHANGES.md). Breaking changes are always explained there.

Do remember you are trying to incorporate over 2 years of active development into your customized editor. There were lots of new features introduced during this time, so your plugins may need some serious adjustments.

As for particular methods, just check the API. Information such as whether something is deprecated or examples how it should be implemented will be there (example: [`editor.addCommand`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addCommand)).

As for building custom plugins, check the [plugin tutorials](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro) for some working code and explanations. The source codes are [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-docs-samples).

Last but not least, remember to clear the browser cache after changing any JavaScript/CSS files. This usually solves most issues with toolbar/menus etc. disappearing after an upgrade or configuration change.

Comment: And I can only add that `editor.addCommand` still exists and nothing serious happened to it, because it is a very basic core method. I advise you, @Ken, to take a closer look at what's not working, because there weren't that many backwards incompatible changes between 4.1 and 4.4. Perhaps you just forgot to include some plugins, or made a similar mistake.

Comment: What I'm seeing in my 4.1 source vs 4.4.7 is a call to 

CKEDITOR.loader.load( '_bootstrap' ); 

Really not sure if the developer who installed 4.1 manually added this tweak (no longer with the company), or if this was purposefully removed by the ckeditor folks?  Either way, this loads functions that are needed, such as the replace function.